# Extension for UIKit protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I want to add default implementation in extension:

```
import UIKit

protocol Animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {}

extension Animator {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.33
    }
}
```

But I have a strange error during compilation:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

and very long stack dump.

Comment: Why are you extending this protocol to have a method that the protocol already has?

Comment: I want to add default implementation for all objects that confirm `Animator` protocol

Comment: You won't be able to do that (as I explain in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add default implementation in extension

You can't. Objective-C cannot see a Swift protocol extension, so your "default implementation" will never be called.

Comment: You have to be kidding. People do this all the time with UIViewController extensions.

Comment: I have trie this with two Swift protocols, but it doesn't works too.

Comment: @DanielT. If you think my answer is wrong, downvote it!

Comment: Matt is correct (as usual.) There are 2 problems. 1.) Objective-C can't see swift protocol extensions. 2.) An extension can't override an existing function. For that you need a subclass, not an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you crashed the compiler. (That's what seg fault 11 means.)

Your Animator class needs to derive from NSObject so that it can conform to the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol.

This works:

```
import UIKit

class Animator: NSObject {

}

extension Animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.33
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It may _compile_ but the implementations will not be seen or called.

Comment: I don't want to extend class or any object that confirm protocol, I want to add implementation for all objects.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Why would a String or an Int need to conform to the transitioning protocol?